# Execute OdbcConnection within a TransactionScope but avoid automatic enlistment

Tags: odbc, intersystems-cache

I'm trying to use the InterSystems Caché ODBC driver to do a simple `SELECT`, but get the following error:

> OdbcException: ERROR [HYC00] [Cache ODBC][State : HYC00][Native Code Driver not capable

I am assuming, based on conversations with colleagues and the otherwise simplicity of the requirement and environment, that this is because the `OdbcConnection` is automatically enlisting in the ambient `TransactionScope`, which isn't supported.

The result of this SQL is fundamental to the coninuation of the `TransactionScope`, which occurs over a `SqlConnection`, so I need to have this nested nature within the security afforded by a `TransactionScope`.

Is there a way I can have the ODBC code, which is fundamental to the `TransactionScope` execute *within* the context of the code, but *outside* the TransactionScope`?

Comment: Have confirmed, executing the above _outside_ of a `TrasactionScope` does work.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a week or so with no responses so one has to assume it isn't possible. (This itself represents knowledge and a place in the StackOverflow corpus).

I've worked around it by disabling transactions for this particular workload.